# how to use query result as a variable in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form, in which a form input field is present for coupon discount. If I click on button then coupon result shows on div section. But I want this result as a variable, by which I can use it on other input field **Total Price**. I want to replace **$total_package_price** by coupon result.

HTML

```html
<li>
            <span class="txt_hd">Total Price</span>
            <span class="txt_inp"><input type="text" name="ttlprice" id="main_price" readonly value="<?php echo $total_package_price; ?>" /></span>
        </li>
 <li style="display:none;" id="apply_omron_dis">
            <span class="txt_hd">To Avail Discount, Put the Coupon Code here</span>
            <span class="txt_inp"><input type="text" name="omron_coupon_code" id="omron_coupon_code" /></span>
           <span class="txt_hd" style="visibility:hidden">To Avail OMRAN Discount, Put the Coupon Code here</span><input type="button" name="apply_coupon" id="apply_coupon" onClick="getcoupon();" value="Apply"/>
            <input type="button" id="cancel" value="cancel"/><span id="txtHint"></span>
        </li>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
   function getcoupon()
  {
  var omron_coupon_code = document.getElementById("omron_coupon_code").value;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","function.php?omron_coupon_code="+omron_coupon_code,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['omron_coupon_code'])){
$omron_coupon_code=$_GET['omron_coupon_code'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("healcrdbxz");

$sql2=mysql_query("select * from coupon_master WHERE coupon_code='$omron_coupon_code'") or die(mysql_error());
//echo $sql2;   
if(mysql_num_rows($sql2)>0)
{
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value) {
    $sql32=mysql_query("select * from package_price WHERE package_id='".$value['package_id']."' and branch_id='".$value['branch']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($packages32 = mysql_fetch_array($sql32))
    {
    extract($packages32);
    $total_package_price=$offer_price;

    echo $total_package_price;
    } 
    }
}
else
 echo "Invalid coupon";
}
```

Comment: you have it as a variable already here: `this.responseText`. It's a bit unclear what the problem is.

Comment: sidenotes: I don't think `$total_package_price` is what you want it to be. I guess you wanna add $offer_price to it in each loop. Then echo/return _after_ the while loop.

Comment: sidenote2: mysql_*  is deprecated, unsecure, removed, dead. use mysqli_* or pdo instead.

Comment: There is a variable $total_package_price; which is total price of any product. But if any one click on apply button then result should be replace with $total_package_price.

Comment: Means result getting from query will replace value of $total_package_price;

Comment: Can I use this.responseText as a php variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156768/discussion-between-user3526766-and-jeff).